# How to partition large buffer to get start, end and length in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

How to partition large buffer to get start, end and length in c#?

like if i have a buffer size of 1048576, how can i partition in to 5 parts?

```
this example is greatly reduce in size

length: 14
start: 0 || end: 2 || length: 3
start: 3 || end: 5 || length: 3
start: 6 || end: 8 || length: 3
start: 9 || end: 11 || length: 3
start: 12 || end: 13 || length: 2
```

**update:** i just need to get the start, end and length, so i can write data on one large buffer, it's kinda like a buffer pool, but with no predefine size, so have i have to partition it into parts.

Comment: Your use of terminology is a little lacking, what do you want to do? Copy parts of your buffer into another array? also dont answer in comments, update your question to be more speicific

Comment: can you provide more information regarding your requirement. by reading this I can guess, you should use List of small buffers instead of one big buffer. and you can have header where you can put properties like start, end, and length so you don't have to read whole buffer for this information.

Comment: `i just need to get the start, end and length,` of what? the buffer you are using ? `so have i have to partition it into parts` this is still very very very vague, help us help you... describe it like you would to a 5 year old, pretend we don't know what you are talking about... show us code, draw pictures if oyu have to

Comment: isn't the example enough of i wan't i want to achieved? too make it simple, i have 10 bytes, and i wan't to partition it in 2, the result would be `first partition start: 0: end 4: length 5` and `second partition start: 5 end: 9 length 5`. now i have two sets of data to use the buffer. but this was easy if it was all equal, the problem is when it's not all same given the buffer size and how many parts i want to partition it

Comment: If you know how to do it for "equal" partitions, Then, it's a simple modification to do it on all cases. Each partition starts from `#OfPartition * partitionSize` and ends at `Start + partitionSize`, except the last one that ends at the last original index. Where do you have difficulties?